# How can i measure my http troughput (up&down-load) from server to client and back?

Tags: linux, bash, troubleshooting, http, wget

I'm looking for a good way to measure my http troughput (up & down load) over a proxy from a server to a client & back.

I'd like to write a (bash) script to download over http (like wget) from client to my server.
The general idea is to download big and small files (option 1 or 2 in the modular script) to measure my http troughput.

What would be the best approach? And, how do I generate big and small files & download these on my client to measure my http troughput efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For measuring some related stats, you can use this script I once wrote: [Wget2: benchmark.sh](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2/blob/master/benchmarks/benchmark.sh)

It's a simple bash script that tries to compare some simple network parameters across a few applications. You can modify it to test with only a single application if you'd like.

This script connects to http://example.com and downloads sample pages of very small size. You should change the link to point to your own server with files of different sizes.

For different files, you can use `dd` to create files with random data of whatever size you want. Or you can simply reuse the files from one of the various bandwidth testing websites out there.

Comment: Many thanks! It looks a little bit confusing to me tho, i'll try to look more into it later, i dont know what you mean with "tries to compare some simple network parameters across a few applications. You can modify it to test with only a single application if you'd like."
Nevertheless, thank you very much for your reply!